# Mongodb : UpdateMany with filter field IN another collection

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to updateMany a collection where the filter is a IN condition from another collection.

In SQL it would be :

```
UPDATE collection1
SET field1 = true
WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM collection2)
```

Input collections

```
collection1 :  [{"_id" : "1", "field1": false},  {"_id" : "2", "field1": false} ]

collection2 : [{"_id" : "1"}, {"_id" : "3"}]
```

Expected result

```
collection1 :  [{"_id" : "1", "field1": true},  {"_id" : "2", "field1": false} ]
```

Comment: [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) should be what you are looking for. Would be helpful if you can provide sample documents and expected output so we can have a closer look

Comment: $lookup is not allowed in an updateMany aggregation pipeline : 

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: @loonis this could be potentially achieved by $merge. But as I said, we would need sample documents and expected output to see if that is really possible.

Comment: Sample of documents added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @ray comment here is my finding.
You can use an aggregation pipeline with a `$merge` into the current collection using `whenMatched: 'replace'` and `whenNotMatched: 'discard'`

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'collection2',
            localField: '_id ',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'collection2_docs'
        }
    },
    {
        //SIMULATE THE INNER JOIN
        $unwind: "$collection2_docs"
    },
    {
        //Update the field
        $set: {
            "field1": true

        }
    },
    {
        //REMOVE THE lookup projection
        $project: {
            collection2_docs: 0

        }
    },
    {
        // Merge into the current collection using whenMatched: 'replace and whenNotMatched: 'discard'
        $merge: {
            into: 'collection1',
            whenMatched: 'replace',
            whenNotMatched: 'discard'
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: replacing the `$match: {"collection2_docs" : {$ne: []}}` with `$unwind` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CA7ENRT8f0m) could be potentially more performant due to [$lookup + $unwind coalesce optimization](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-lookup----unwind-coalescence)

Comment: Thank you @ray, this optimization is much appreciated. I updated the answer accordingly.